# Need to read Ember component property as array of model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I passed the result of `this.store.findAll('something')` to a component so I could create a dropdown control. Everything works great but I'd like to find the object I selected by reading this property.

Everything I read says its bad practice to inject the store into these components and since I already have the data in the property I thought it would be easy to read. However it's in an Ember model array that doesn't seem to be so easy to open because the array is deep down the stack.

I started heading down something like `this.get('myprop').content`... but I wondered if this was the correct way to do this. It seems I should be able to open them as the model they should be.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You can use `.toArray()`. Bot for your use case probably use `.find`.

Comment: Without more info about the structure of the data we can't really help you. I suggest giving [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) a read.

Comment: findAll() returns a promise which you should access with something like findAll().then(function(dataList) { dataList.forEach(function(aData) { ... });});

Comment: How are you building the dropdown control in the DOM? Most Ember Addons for `select` provide access to the selected option as part of their API. You can use actions (or the `mut` helper) to "bubble" this property back up. I don't recommend searching in the array to find the selected object-- treat it as a separate property.

Answer (score 1):

it turns out the best way I could find to select my model was the 'peek' function. Not exactly what I wanted to do but it works.

*Some of the comments below my initial question also work, but nobody ever actually added an answer so this is my answer.* :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer @hopeful-Ember-developer . I think it would be good to also point out, that your solution works now because  `peekAll` has an Array as its return value and not - as before - a Promise when using `findAll` (References in the doc: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll and http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekAll).

Comment: you are correct @Jessica, at the time I had not realized the differences in what is returned... wrongly assumed a returned object would be the same object for any "Get" method for that object... sheesh, what was I thinking. :)